# HTML5 <a> Download Attribute in Javascript not Handling Server Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html

I'm trying to programmatically click an `<a>` element which has the download attribute and an href to download a file from a server. However if there is an error downloading, the server will return an html page with an error status code. Because of the HTML5 download attribute it tries to force download this html page or downloads a server error file. Is there a way I can have this open the html error file in a new tab instead of downloading? I am already setting the target attribute to _blank.

Comment: what you had try so far? your codes?

Answer (score 1):

You can request the file using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`, if no error occurs, set `<a>` element `href`, `download` attributes, else redirect user to document displaying error response.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new element, e.g. button and use clickevent with jquery ajax request to check that server is available.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/url/to/file",
    type: "GET",
    success: //handle succes -> download file,
    error: //handle error
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the browser does not offer us a mechanism to override the default on that matter, what you can do instead, is what others have already pointed out, but this answer builds on top of the previous ones.

If you have control over the web server, you can add an endpoint for the `HEAD` method, alongside the endpoint for the `GET` method. The `HEAD` method asks for a response identical to that of a `GET` request, but without the response body, which is great for this use case.

Imagine that the file is 1GB in size (or higher), the download time (using `XHR` or `fetch`) would be big, just to know if the file exists. If you cache the response, once you try to download the file to the user device, the download time would be much faster, but if you can't cache the file, it would take again the same amount of time.

Using the `HEAD` method to verify if the file exists, you just download the response headers and not the body (file), so the request will complete much faster. On the response, just verify the status code (`200` or `404`) to determine the validity of the file.

[MDN Docs Head method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD)